# How can I hide a Tumblr sidebar widget from pages?

Tags: widget, blogs, tumblr, sidebar, custom-pages

I've added a widget to my Tumblr sidebar and I don't want it to show on Ask and other custom pages.

I used the following code

```
{block:PermalinkPagination}
   ...code...
{/block:PermalinkPagination}
```

It didn't work.

I've tried wrapping between these codes as well.

```
{block:HasPages}
   ...code...
{/block:HasPages}
```

```
{block:Pages}
   ...code...
{/block:Pages}
```

```
{block:Date}
   ...code...
{/block:Date}
```

but it's still showing up on the pages. I'd like to remove the widget on Ask and other static pages. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `{block:IndexPage}`. It should not be true for custom pages or the Ask page.

```
{block:IndexPage}
    ...code...
{/block:IndexPage}
```

For permalink pages use:

```
{block:PermalinkPage} 
    ...code...
{/block:PermalinkPage}
```

Comment: This is working. It blocks my widget to show up on Ask and other static pages but I want to show my widget on posts page!

Comment: @CyberCriminal For permalink pages you can use:     `{block:PermalinkPage}`